# field with type="time" in tx_form

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

Seems that my question is not clear. I will try to explain it in more detail:

Txform offers the following field types for date and time:

- Date: <input type="date" ....>
- DatePicker: <input type="date" ... > but with a javascript date picker.

I cannot use one of them because i do not need date but only time. There should not be any possibility to enter a date - only time should be possible, e. g. 10:00. In html5 there is a field type which offers this feature:

```
<input type="time" ... >
```

In most browsers you get a wizard for entering time, especially on mobile devices. But i found no way to build it with txform. Is there a possiblity to get a form field with input type time?

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Please improve your question it's totally unclear.